# Java regex to filter strings starting with a pattern and end after first ] appearance

Tags: java, regex

I need to select from a log file only the parts containing a begining string /epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=*] until the first ] and exclude from selection all other variants, so only the first 15 lines to be selected. * can be alphanumeric . or -.

(/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=(.*))(](?=/)){1}

with this regex I can select the part I don't want. I can select all or a part but I didn't find a way to select only /epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=*] until the first ] and discard all others. Please help me if you know how to. Thank you very much.

This is my list of strings from which I must select the patterns from the first part:

```
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=babspaylink.apn.tln.se]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=cinter.apn.tln.se]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=gps-bud.be]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=sensi-two.com]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=tln1.mic-o-data.nl.com]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=tlnr01.mixtel.com]">
<measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=vtc.apn.vd.net]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=gprs01.fela.com]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=gprs1.gt.com]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=gprs2.gt.com]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=xlm.com]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=xylem.com]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=xylem.sam.com]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=xylemat.com]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=xylemfi.com]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=vbc.com]/service-identifier-stats[value=1102]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=vbc.com]/service-identifier-stats[value=1214]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=vbc.com]/service-identifier-stats[value=299]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=vtc.apn.vd.net]/service-identifier-stats[value=1001]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=vtc.apn.vd.net]/service-identifier-stats[value=1102]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=vtc.apn.vd.net]/service-identifier-stats[value=1203]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=vbc.com]/service-based-charging/rule-space-stats[name=vbc_com_rs]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=vtc.apn.vd.net]/service-based-charging/rule-space-stats[name=vtc_apn_vd_rs]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=vtc.apn.vd.net]/rating-group-stats[value=100]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=vtc.apn.vd.net]/rating-group-stats[value=110]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=aenams01.com]/radius/authentication/server[address=10.224.3.1]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=aenprosess.com]/radius/authentication/server[address=10.224.1.8]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=vpn.kayp.com]/radius/accounting/server[address=188.92.2.40]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=vpn.kayp.com]/radius/accounting/server[address=188.92.1.41]">
    <measValue measObjLdn="/epg:epg/pgw/apn[name=wlapn.com]/radius/accounting/server[address=10.3.0.1]">
```

Comment: Can you include your current code for handling this log file?  There are a few ways to go about doing this.

Comment: I cannot paste the code but is using regex of Java 8 from this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/dZmT9L/2

Comment: thank you very much. is good, but can we exclude from selection all the lines from service-identifier-stats to bottom?

Comment: (\/epg:epg\/pgw\/apn\[name=(.*?)\]){1}+(?!\/)       - the solution I finally found after checking more around Wiktor response